# Post installation of PowerShell - PWSH command not found

Tags: command-line, powershell

I have just installed PowerShell on my Ubuntu server (18.04) using the command `dotnet tool install --global PowerShell`. After completing the installation sequence I was presented with `You can invoke the tool using the following command: pwsh
Tool 'powershell' (version '6.2.3') was successfully installed.`
When I attempt to run the command `pwsh` I am receiving "Command not found" error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `~/.dotnet/tools` to your $PATH